# unit test HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute

Tags: spring-boot

This is controller:

```
@Controller("person")
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class SomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Valid Person person, Model model, @ModelAttribute("name") String name, BindingResult result) {}
}
```

This is Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PersonTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "ram", authorities={"TEACHER"})
    public void checkPersonInfoWhenNameMissingNameThenFailure() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder createPerson = post("/person/add")
                .param("aa", "bb");

        mockMvc.perform(createPerson)
                .andExpect(model().hasErrors());
    }
}
```

Because controller needs a session attribute "name", so the above test throws:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute 'name'
```

How to test controller methods that requires session attribute?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MockMvc has a method to set session attributes.

[Session attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#sessionAttr-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)